# Trying to use Cfhttp to post a image to a remote server that uses iFrame to upload Images

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, cfml, ajax-upload, cfhttp

**I am tyring to upload a image to a remote server using cfhttp,
this is the basic code the remote server uses , they are using AjaxUploader and Jquery , 
I cant figure out how to send the image,

i would also like to get back the name of the image after it is uploaded;

if I do a manual upload with the code below i see the server changes the name of the image

how can I write the cfm code that would show me the name of the uploaded image?

I stripped as much as i could and kept the code down to a minimum, i thought this would be a 30 minute task its turned into 10 hours, please help :-(**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

var NREUMQ=NREUMQ||[];NREUMQ.push(["mark","firstbyte",new Date().getTime()]);

</script>

<title>uploader for Souq.com</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

var CDNHOST='https://d1jztyon2mtydf.cloudfront.net/' ;
var HOSTSSL = 'https://ssl.souq.com/ae-en';
var HOST = 'http://uae.souq.com/ae-en';
var STATICHOST = 'https://d1jztyon2mtydf.cloudfront.net/static/ltr/en';
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js?refresh=2010-03-24"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajaxupload.js?refresh=1276881171"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var _sf_async_config={uid:16343,domain:"ssl.souq.com"};
(function(){
function loadChartbeat() {
window._sf_endpt=(new Date()).getTime();
var e = document.createElement('script');
e.setAttribute('language', 'javascript');
e.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
e.setAttribute('src',
(("https:" == document.location.protocol) ?
"https://a248.e.akamai.net/chartbeat.download.akamai.com/102508/" : 
"http://static.chartbeat.com/") +
"js/chartbeat.js");
document.body.appendChild(e);
}
var oldonload = window.onload;
window.onload = (typeof window.onload != 'function') ?
loadChartbeat : function() { oldonload();
loadChartbeat(); };
})();</script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function(){var a=document.createElement("script");
var b=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
a.src=document.location.protocol+"//dnn506yrbagrg.cloudfront.net/pages/scripts/0014/1335.js

?"+Math.floor(new Date().getTime()/3600000);
a.async=true;
a.type="text/javascript";
b.parentNode.insertBefore(a,b)}, 1);
</script>
</head>
<body>



<iframe id="gallery_item_iframe" name="gallery_item_iframe" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="155px" src="https://ssl.souq.com/ae-en/gallery_uploads.php?item_gallery=1" scrolling="no">

</iframe>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I imagine this happening on the client side would be quite difficult.

Answer (score 0):

i'd start by capturing the http headers sent when you upload an image through the browser with firebug for example. Then you know how to craft the cfhttp call. You may also have to setup cookies if the client requires this. Assuming of course they dont implement guards against bots which is what a cfhttp call will look like.